# Which function controls the product image change?

Tags: javascript, magento

http://www.wargame-club.com/3-day-molle-assault-backpack-black.html

When I click the four product thumbnail images under the big product image, the product image will change. I find there is no `click` function on the `a` label. How does it make the product image on the thumbnail images change? Thank you.

```
<li>
  <a title="" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="popupWin:'http://www.wargame-club.com/catalog/product/gallery/id/24/image/83/', useZoom: 'cloudZoom', smallImage: 'http://www.wargame-club.com/media/catalog/product/cache/6/image/265x265/fa17b1d835a4c57a29916eae7df1805d/A/S/AS043_2.jpg'" href="http://www.wargame-club.com/media/catalog/product/cache/6/image/fa17b1d835a4c57a29916eae7df1805d/A/S/AS043_2.jpg"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Its likely defined in `/skin/frontend/base/default/js/em_cloudzoom/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js`

Comment: "i find there is no click function on the a label." -- thankfully. Using `addEventListener` or it equivalent from [your popular framework] is much better.

Comment: @techfoobar,do u know which function controls it? i read the file over, but not find a function controls it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**When you inspect the page and check the javascript files, you will get to the:**
http://www.wargame-club.com/js/cjm/colorselectorplus/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js

In this file you will find the following code:

```
 $(this).bind('click', $(this), function (event) {

var data = event.data.data('relOpts');

// Destroy the previous zoom
$('#' + data.useZoom).data('zoom').destroy();

// Change the biglink to point to the new big image.
$('#' + data.useZoom).attr('href', event.data.attr('href'));

// Change the small image to point to the new small image.
$('#' + data.useZoom + ' img').attr('src', event.data.data('relOpts').smallImage);

// Init a new zoom with the new images.
$('#' + event.data.data('relOpts').useZoom).CloudZoom();
```

}

**the script used is:**
http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom

Comment: many thanks.now, if i want to when click the thumbnail image, the big image will not show the watermask, but when the mouse hover on the big image, it will show the watermask. how to change the code? thank you

Comment: the effect like your first open the product page, there is no watermask on the big image.when you hover your mouse on it. it will show.